# There is a compact neighborhood $N$ of $x$ such that $N \subset U.$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> If $X$ is an LCH space, $U \subset X$ is open, and $x \in U,$ there is a compact neighborhood $N$ of $x$ such that $N \subset U.$

The proof of the above goes along the following lines $:$

> We may assume that $\overline {U}$ is compact; otherwise, replace $U$ by $U \cap F^{\circ}$ where $F$ is a compact neighborhood of $x.$ Then there are disjoint relatively open subsets $V,W \subset \overline {U}$ such that $x \in V$ and $\partial U \subset W.$ Then $V$ is open in  $X$ since $V \subset U$ and $\overline {V}$ is closed and hence a compact subset of $U \setminus W.$ Thus we may take $N = \overline {V}.$

I don't understand why $\overline {V} \subset U \setminus W.$ We only know that $V \cap W = \varnothing.$ How does it imply that $\overline {V} \cap W = \varnothing\ $? Any help in this regard would be warmly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

**Source** $:$ Proposition $4.30$ in Folland's Real Analysis (Page no. $131$).

Comment: what is an LCH space?

Comment: @Marcos locally compact Hausdorff space.

Comment: $V$ stays away from the boundary of $U$ so is a subset of $U$ not just of $\overline{U} = U \cup \partial U$, and so is $\overline{V}$.